# Finding the Generating Function given a Complex Recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have the following recurrence relation:

$G_0=0, G_1=1,$
$$\left(G+\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+\left(G+\frac{1+w_3}{3}\right)^n+\left(G+\frac{1+w_3^2}{3}\right)^n=0, n>1$$
where $w_3$ is the primitive $3$rd root of unity, and in the math of the [Umbral Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus), the exponents of G are brought down as subscripts once the expansion occurs.

For those who don't know how this works, take the Bernoulli numbers.  They can be defined by the following recurrence:

$B_0=1, B_1=\frac{-1}{2}$
$$(B+1)^n-B^n=0, n>1$$

So take $n=3$.  Then

$$(B+1)^3-B^3=0\Rightarrow B^3+3B^2+3B+1-B^3=0\Rightarrow 3B_2+3B_1+1=0$$

Thus since $B_1=-1/2$, we can solve for $B_2$.

$$3B_2-\frac{3}{2}+1=0\Rightarrow 3B_2=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow B_2=\frac{1}{6}$$

I'm not even sure I know where to begin.  I can simply find a few of the coefficients using Mathematica or Maple, but how do I find the exponential generating function?

Comment: Your expression is not an equation, and doesn't show how to compute $G_{n+1}$ from previous values. Did you mean to put $G_{n+1}=$ to the left of the expression? And include some subscripts on the $G$'s inside?

Comment: Sorry.  This is what happens when you write a post at midnight.  I will amend the question.

Comment: There are still no subscripts on the three $G$'s in the equation. Should they all be $n$ or maybe $n,n+1,n+2$ in some order?

Comment: There not need be subscripts.  I put a link to the Umbral Calculus which explains why there are no subscripts in the original expression.